# How to get the html so its not encoded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the value of a **fckeditor** with javascript to show in a dialog as preview. Now I want it to show the html tags like I input them but instead it shows me this

```
<p>&lt;div&gt;test&lt;/div&gt;</p>
```

that is `<div>test</div>`

I use this following code

```
function test() {
        var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKeditor1');
        var pageValue = oEditor.GetHTML(true);

        alert(pageValue);            
    }
```

I have tried to change settings like

```
FCKConfig.HtmlEncodeOutput = false;
FCKConfig.ProcessHTMLEntities = true;
FCKConfig.FormatSource = false;
```

No luck with that. I am getting a little frustrated with this problem now.
Anybody got a idea why?

Comment: Have you tried `GetHTML(false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the DOM?

```
function unescapeHTML(html) {
    var htmlNode = document.createElement("div");
    htmlNode.innerHTML = html;
    if(htmlNode.innerText)
    return htmlNode.innerText; // IE
   return htmlNode.textContent; // FF
}
```

([source](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=14))

Comment: great code. dont know if it workes flawless but I will be testing it. thanks justkt

Answer (score -1):

@Pointy yes I did. Solved it tho.

```
.replace(/\&lt;/g, '<').replace(/\&gt;/g, '>')
```

Comment: If the output is truly HTML encoded then just replacing angle-brackets won't be enough.

Comment: yes I know but seem like the fckeditor just remove the < >. It work for the moment, I still have to the full scale html test on it.